# How to add row to pandas DataFrame with missing value efficiently?

Tags: python, performance, pandas

Suppose I have a many rows with different column names, how to add them to a pandas' DataFrame more efficiently.

```
d = pd.DataFrame()
a = {'a':10,'b':1.3}
b = {'b':32.5,'c':3.14, 'm': 5.1}
```

I want the result like this:

```
d = 
     a   b  c  m
 1  10 1.3  0  0 
 2  0  32.5 3.14 5.1
```

There are two ways:

1.

```
d = d.append(pd.DataFrame(a,index=[1]))
d = d.append(pd.DataFrame(b,index=[2]))
```

2. get all unique column names first,then

```py
column_name = ['a','b','c','m']
d = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_name)
d.add(a)
d.add(b)
```

As the first way need `join`, so should way 2 be faster than way 1?

Or there are any better solution?

Comment: you will get `Nan` rather than a `0`

Comment: That's not a big deal, just `d.fillna(0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also could try to use [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html). Your 2nd method isn't working properly (or may be I missed something). Results:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a, index=[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b, index=[1])

d = pd.DataFrame()
d = d.append(df1)
d = d.append(df2).fillna(0)

In [107]: d
Out[107]: 
    a     b     c    m
0  10   1.3  0.00  0.0
1   0  32.5  3.14  5.1


column_name = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'm']
d = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_name)
d.add(a)
d.add(b)

In [113]: d
Out[113]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c, m]
Index: []


In [115]: pd.concat([df1, df2]).fillna(0)
Out[115]: 
    a     b     c    m
0  10   1.3  0.00  0.0
1   0  32.5  3.14  5.1

d = pd.DataFrame()
In [144]: d.combine_first(df1).combine_first(df2).fillna(0)
Out[144]: 
    a     b     c    m
0  10   1.3  0.00  0.0
1   0  32.5  3.14  5.1
```

Benchmarking:

```
In [86]: %%timeit
d = pd.DataFrame()
d = d.append(df1)
d = d.append(df2).fillna(0)
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.29 ms per loop

In [87]: %timeit c = pd.concat([df1, df2]).fillna(0)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.94 ms per loop

In [153]: %%timeit
   .....: d = pd.DataFrame()
   .....: d.combine_first(df1).combine_first(df2).fillna(0)
   .....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.17 ms per loop
```

From these method `pd.concat` is faster

Comment: Thanks, `pd.concat` is really faster.